# Rsync permission issues via SSH

Tags: server, ssh, backup, rsync, migration

I am backing up a networked server via SSH. Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to get root access to the networked server with Rsync. I am using the following command to perform the backup:

```
sudo rsync -av ubuntu@*******:/ /media/backup1/ubuntubackup
```

Some directories come up as permission denied. Once I log in through Rsync, the backup just starts and there is no way to issue the sudo command. I understand that I can use the Rsync daemon to get around this, but I would like to use SSH without the daemon for the sake of simplicity. Does anyone know a way to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this on Amazon Cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is you are taking 'sudo' on the local box and not on the remote server. I have not verified this, but a structure like the following should work:

```
rsync -R -avz -e ssh --rsync-path="echo mypassword | \
    sudo rsync" /media/backup1/ubuntubackup ubuntu@*******:/ /media/backup1/ubuntubackup
```